# How to retry a service method upon getting an OptimisticLockException with JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I have had some problems with dirty writes in hibernate. I have added @version fields so that I can see if I am writing to an out of date table. This has meant that I now have lots of boilerplate code that does

```
try {
   tryWriteToTable();
} catch (PersistenceExcepton) {  //subclasss of OptimisiticLockException
   try {
      tryWriteToTable();
   } catch (PersistenceExcepton) {
       //dont try again - something seriously wrong
   }
}
```

I am using Spring and wondered if there is anything in that which will allow me to define this pattern. Something that will allow me to repeat if there is an exception. Other than Spring is there anything else I could use in order for me to avoid all this ugly boilerplate code.

I would like something like this

```
@TryTwice
private void tryWriteToTable() ....
```

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best way to achieve your goal is to use an interceptor that catches the `OptimisticLockingException` and allows you to retry the operation.

However, note that this will work only if you get the latest entity snapshot and copy the detached state without the old version property. A strategy like this is prone to lost updates.

Therefore, you should use the retry strategy only if the subset of entity properties you are trying to save can only be updated by your own process, and not by any other concurrent transaction.

To simplify the task, I created the [`db-util` open-source project](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/db-util), which is available on Maven Central as well. It's based on Spring AOP, and it offers a `@Retry` annotation to mark the services which you want to be retried upon getting an optimistic locking exception.

Comment: Hi @Vlad Mihalcea, what would be a proper solution if you are also in a transaction? Not to retry at all? Thank you

Comment: Try [this versionless optimistic locking strategy](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-prevent-optimisticlockexception-using-hibernate-versionless-optimistic-locking/).

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is something ready-made for this retry problematic. There is also a better pattern for your current task at hand instead of trying to redo something or catching PersistenceException objects.

Since you are using Spring and most likely use [Java Transaction Service (JTA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_transaction_service) for transaction handling or use Hibernate in JPA compatible mode. Therefore the persistence context of the session will be cleared after a transaction commit. This makes your entity to become detached with the current (and therefore any) session.

So every change you made for the given entity is not managed by the session anymore (if your entity is still managed by the session you can use `session.evict(entity)` to detach it manually. You might want to read something about detached objects in the Hibernate documentation: [Working with detached objects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-detached).

Now you can reload the current state of the database element the entity is representing by just using `MyEntity currentState = session.get(EntityClass.class, detachedEntity.getId());`. By inspecting the properties of the currentState object you can easily test the version numbers. If it differs the state within the database has changed and you can test for special conditions and act accordingly.

**Example**:

For example we use something I implemented some time ago. We have a email system sending certain business reports to the people in charge. To create a email it takes 5 minutes or more. Creating the emails is delayed after midnight to not disrupt daily operations (the database utilization to create those reports is huge)

So our (untested, just for illustration) code looks like this:

```
session.beginTransaction();
EmailTask task = getRandomNextTask(session);
session.getTransaction().commit(); //end transaction, task is detached

prepareEmail(); //takes 5minutes or more

session.beginTransaction();
EmailTask currentState = session.get(EmailTask.class, task.getId());
if(currentState.getVersion() == task.getVersion() || currentState.hasError()) {
     currentState.markDone();
     session.getTransaction().commit();
     sendEmail();
} 
else
    trashEmail();
```

So you can see we first get the next email task and start computing the email which takes some time. Then we check if the task is not altered or if some other process has altered it we check if the process actually did not send the email (since it resulted in an error). If so we mark the task as being done and actually send the email. (we just assume our system does not crash after changing the database but before actually sending the email.